# Examples of $f \in L^p$ iff $p_0 < p < p_1$, $p_0 \le p \le p_1$ or $p = p_0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose $0 < p_0 < p_1 \leq \infty$. Find examples of functions $f$ on $(0,\infty)$
with Lebesgue measure such that $f \in L^p$

if and only if

(a) $p_0 < p < p_1$
(b) $p_0 \leq p \leq p_1$
(c) $p=p_0$

The hint says consider functions of the form $f(x) = x^{-a}|\log x|^b$
but the hint does not help since integral is divergent for any choice of $a$ and $b$

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, that is if your $f$ is over the entire interval. That does not have to the be the case. You can consider $x\log x$ on $(1,\infty)$, say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give you one example and let you fill in the details and find the other examples.

---

This integral converges iff $p > p_0$:
$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{p/p_0}}
$$

You can show this by direct computation.

---

This integral converges iff $p \le p_1$:
$$
\int_0^{1/e} \frac{dx}{\left(x(\log x)^2\right)^{p/p_1}}
$$

The case $p = p_1$ follows by direct computation. The cases $p < p_1$ and $p > p_1$ follow by comparison with integrals similar to the previous intergral.

---

Put:
$$
f(x) = \frac{\chi_{(2,\infty)}}{x^{1/p_0}} + \frac{\chi_{(0, 1/e)}}{\left(x(\log x)^2\right)^{1/p_1}}
$$

And show that $f \in L^p((0, \infty))$ iff $p_0 < p \le p_1$.

Comment: How are you supposed to evaluate this integral$$
\int_0^{1/e} \frac{dx}{\left(x(\log x)^2\right)^{p/p_1}}
$$